# Google Script with Spreadsheet - Function to Count Column Values

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a Google spreadsheet where I'll enter a bunch of data into that spreadsheet, then on another sheet, I want to pull statistics from it. I'm having a hard time counting the values correctly.

**What I'm attempting to accomplish**
- Build a function that I can add to any cell to get the statistics of a certain column by counting repeating values based on the target/argument in the function.

Example:

> Sheet 1 has the data I need to calculate in column E (holds 1 or 2 letters to indicate a status.
>    Sheet 2 is where I will pull all statistical data.
>    I add a function like so:   =getData("A")
>
> The function itself would already point to sheet1 and column E. What the function is saying here is, "I want you to pull all of the data in column E and tell me how many cells are marked as A" and then give me the count.
>
> I have about 5 different values I would independantly search for here. We'll say A, B, C, D and E. So if I go to search for C, I would pull the stats into another cell on my statistics sheet using: =getData("C")

**What I've gotten so far (that doesn't work)**
- I'm pretty sketchy at coding this stuff, so I'm still learning a lot. Here's what I was attempting so far:

```
function getData(target) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET1");
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(2, 5, lrow, 1);
  var data = r.getValues();
  var count;

  for (var i = 0; i < lrow ; i++) {
    var count = 1;
    for (var j = 0; j < i; i++) {
      if (data[j][0].value(target) == data[i][0].value(target)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  return (count);
  }
}
```

I also tried:
    if (data.value() == target) { count++; }

But that didn't seem to help either. What am I doing wrong? Either I'm not counting correctly and/or not pulling the data to count it correctly. I've searched quite a few posts and can't seem to pull together what I need.

I appreciate any help anyone could offer. Thanks.

---

**Resolved Code ( Thanks @ScampMichael )** - This slight variation actually allows me to search for multiple values using the format =getData("Example1","Example2") and counting the total:

```
function getData(target1, target2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET1");
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(2, 5, lrow-1, 1); // lrow-1 to not count header
  var data = r.getValues();
  var count = 0; // 0 must be declared here or you'll get error: Overflow on the spreadsheet

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == target1) { // can repeat this part depending how many values you want to search for
      count++;
    }
    if (data[i][0] == target2) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return (count);
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have considered using the standard spreadsheet functions?  Very easy to do counting and summing (if what you are counting or summing is straight-forward).

Comment: I have considered it. The problem in that case is that the complexity of each statistic I'll be getting would require a bunch of spreadsheet code all over my sheet. By building a function, although a little more complex then a single use spreadsheet function, I will actually simply the formula side of things. This will also allow my manager to modify the function based on what they're looking for in the future or if we add additional statuses later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: I missed   var r = ss.getRange(2, 5, lrow, 1); should be

```
 var r = ss.getRange(2, 5, lrow - 1, 1);  // because starting at row 2
```

Because your source data is only one column wide you do not need a loop within a loop but I have left it so in case you desire to have more than one column in your source.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if (data[i][j] == target) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
```

for a single column you could:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
      if (data[i][0] == target) {
        count++;
    }
  }
```

There is also the built in function:  =COUNTIF(SHEET1!E2:E,"A")

Comment: Hello ScampMichael. From what you're showing me, I was sooooo close. I tried your code though and now when I add =getData("A"), I am getting an error on the Google spreadsheet in that cell stating: [#NUM! - error: Overflow. If I try =getData(A) {no quotes}, then I get [#NAME? - error: Unknown range name A].

Comment: Hey Steve, You do need the quotes. I don't see the problem. Would you please edit your question and paste the code in exactly as you have it from the script editor?  Also, just for grins, try initializing your count variable with zero -- var count = 0;

Comment: That was it. I had to declare count = 0 and it worked as intended. Along with that, I was able to give multiple targets. I'm adding the final code to the above post. Thanks a lot @ScampMichael.